# How long can a yeast starter survive in the fridge?

Tags: yeast-starters

I've made a 2L yeast starter (Wyeast 2633 Octoberfest) and placed in the fridge this morning.  My original goal was to brew tonight but I may not be able to.  Will the yeast colony still be good for a few days if it remains in fridge?

Comment: Good question, one that everyone should know the answer too if you when you start using starters and reclaiming yeast.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It should be fine if you store it in the fridge for up to 1-2 weeks.  I have heard you could let it go longer but to be on the safe side I would use it sooner rather than later.  If you do let it sit longer you could always decant the liquid and add more wort to get it going again.

Comment: Great!  Sounds like a few days will be no problem then.

Comment: Hey Bob, how about up-voting the answer if you are going to accept it?  I just up-voted from zero!

Comment: It can actually go alot more than that, if you keep it fed and happy. If you are *very* careful you can go your entire brewing career with just *one* yeast purchased, just keep 2dl in the fridge, and when you want to brew you add 1 litre of wort, and use it like a normal starter, but save 2dl.